Has anyone got a *persistent* remote desktop solution for 24.04?
I've just installed 24.04.1 on a headless box which must be accessed remotely from Windows clients. The connection must be persistent: in other words, if I set up an overnight regression run, or start a simulation, and then close down the Windows viewer and go home, the program must still be running when I connect again in the morning.
I've just tried RDP. It's very pretty, but not persistent, so can't be used for serious work.
I've historically done this over VNC (Ubuntu up to 22.04 and RHEL). However, VNC clients are universally (I think) X-based and don't understand Wayland. I can enable X to run a VNC server in 24.04, but it doesn't work properly, and crashes when I connect from Windows. The problem appears to be with device drivers, and I can't find a fix after several hours looking. Ubuntu is obviously trying to deprecate X, but there are still lots of apps out there that require it.
RDP will apparently become persistent, but this requires Gnome 47 and is unlikely to be back-ported to 24.04 (which is on Gnome 46).
Fixes? Or do I have to go back to 22.04, or RHEL/etc?

Are you running a task via a text user interface (command line) or a graphical user interface? If via a text user interface, you can run it in the background using nohup or cron and it will be independent of any connection to a client computer.

I use x11vnc on 24.04 over SSH.
First I set up iptables and ip6tables to reject incoming connections except SSH, because I run x11vnc without a password or encryption.
Next I start x11vnc on the server. What I do is:
myvnc () 
{ 
    for i in {1..100};
    do
        x11vnc -noxfixes -repeat -display :1;
    done
}

So every time x11vnc crashes or exits (it does sometimes crash) it will start again. Note this is running without a password and without encryption. This makes it more compatible with bad VNC clients that don't implement the full protocol properly, such as maybe the Windows client, though I haven't tested that.
Then I SSH from the client to the server, forwarding port 5900 to localhost:5900 on the client. This provides the security and encryption and also allows me to get into my VNC from anywhere, plus I'd probably be keeping an SSH connection open anyway. Then I start the vnc client (e.g. Remmina) connecting to localhost:5900 on the client machine.
Sometimes x11vnc will get into a bad state without actually crashing (e.g. if the client terminates the connection improperly). In that case just killall x11vnc, so the next instance of it will pop up from the loop, and you can connect again. (Optionally) I have my "myvnc" command running from inside emacs on the server, which I connect to over SSH using emacsclient, so what I usually do instead of killall x11vnc is just switch to the buffer running myvnc and press ctrl-c to kill the current x11vnc and start a new one.
It kind of sounds bad to have all these contingencies for x11vnc crashing or freezing or the VNC client being bad, but most of the time the contingencies aren't needed. They are helpful if you happen to be connecting from a client device that will frequently break the connection, such as a phone. SSH key authentication without a vnc password also makes re-connection quick.

Agreeing here this is a huge issue. The main benefit/use of RDP is missing.
Relying on a perfect connection to the host in order to maintain/finish tasks is shortsighted. We live in a world where connections may be lost (vpn reconnect, wifi disconnect, notebook battery dies, router reboots) and/or otherwise unnecessary (shut down client and leave) or impossible to maintain (airplane). If the connection doesn't remain solid, then the session is signed out. The biggest impact for me has been with lengthy file copying that halts somewhere in the middle due to an occasional disconnect. However, keeping another computer on the whole time while the files are copying is also nonsense.
